# Unity IoC resolving a Generic Service plus Generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, unity-container, repository-pattern

When using ASP.NET MVC plus Entity Framework, and trying to implement a generic repository and a generic service, and have everything resolved by Unity Ioc:

I am trying to get Unity Ioc to inject a generic service into the controller using parameter injection, but the type resolving is failing with this this error message:

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   ISupplierService The current build operation  (build key Build
>   Key[MyApp.Services.Implementation.SupplierService, null]) failed: 
>   Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   IGenericRepository`1,  key \"\" Resolution of the dependency failed: 
>   The current type,
>   MyApp.Repository.Interfaces.IGenericRepository`1[Entities.Supplier],
>   is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?  (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)

I can understand that the error message means that it is trying to create an instance of IGenericRepository when instead I am actually trying to get it to create an instance of SupplierService, but I do not see why it is resolving this way.  As per initial answers it could be because the types are not registered

The controller's service injection is:

```
public class SupplierController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISupplierService _service;
    public SupplierController() : this (null) { }
    public SupplierController(ISupplierService service) 
    {
        _service = service; 
    }
    // .. injection fails, service is NULL
}
```

Supplier service is an empty interface plus empty class (which could have custom methods added later if needed)

```
public partial interface ISupplierService : IGenericService<Supplier> {}
```

IGenericService simply resurfaces the IGenericRepository's methods:

```
public interface IGenericService<T> : IDisposable where T : BaseEntity {}
```

In Global.asax.cs the IoC container is created by

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var uri = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(uri.AbsolutePath);
var assemblyPaths = new List<string> 
{
    Path.Combine(path, "MyApp.Repository.Interfaces.dll"),
    Path.Combine(path, "MyApp.Repository.Implementation.dll"),
    Path.Combine(path, "MyApp.Services.Interfaces.dll"),
    Path.Combine(path, "MyApp.Services.Implementation.dll")
};

container
    .ConfigureAutoRegistration()
    .LoadAssembliesFrom(assemblyPaths)
    .ExcludeSystemAssemblies()
    .Include(If.Any, Then.Register())
    .ApplyAutoRegistration();

var serviceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
```

Comment: Can you show the setup code of your container?

Comment: do you have any additional ctors in your SupplierController?

Comment: @SebastianWeber updated with the container code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

experimented with UnityAutoRegistration while the latest release was still "fresh" and I was not happy with it. The [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AdvancedConfigurationEngineForUnity&referringTitle=Documentation) contains a port of the StructureMap config engine which gives you support for conventions that should make your life a lot easier.

Something like

```cs
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.Scan(s =>
{
  s.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
  s.With(new ImplementsIInterfaceNameConvention());
}
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddExtension(builder);
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
var serviceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
```

should register all of your Interface/Service and Interface/Repository pairs. The convention registers `SupplierService` as the implementation of `ISupplierService` etc.
The additional call to `RegisterType` with the two open generic types (`IGenericRepositoy<>` and `GenericRepository`) maps your generic repository interface to the generic repository class. Unity will close the type definition automatically for you (i.e. `IGenericRepository<Supplier>` will be mapped to `GenericRepository<Supplier>`).

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading that linked project now.  When they say "This makes for rather verbose configuration of the container." (referring to unity), what is the verbose configuration method?

Comment: @JK You would have to add the mapping interface -> service manually for every service. `container.RegisterType<ISupplierService, SupplierService>(); container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();` and so on.

Comment: +1 Manually adding `container.RegisterType<ISupplierService, SupplierService>();` and so on has fixed the problem, thanks.  I'll look into your suggested codeproject config engine, because  `.ConfigureAutoRegistration()` and `.ApplyAutoRegistration()` do not seem to be working as expected.